# payroll_items_controller_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) displayed in Rspec Controller code

Tags: ruby, rspec, controllers

Below is the controller code in rspec for a master item.

To be very frank I'm very new to Ruby with a little knowledge of coding.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PayrollItemsController , "with valid params" do
  before(:each) do
    @payroll_item = mock_model(PayrollItem, :update_attributes => true)
    PayrollItem.stub!(:find).with("1").and_return(@payroll_item)
  end

  it "should find PayrollItem and return object" do
    PayrollItem.should_receive(:find).with("0").and_return(@payroll_item)
  end

  it "should update the PayrollItem object's attributes" do
    @payroll_item.should_receive(:update_attributes).and_return(true)
  end
end
```

When I run the controller code, following error displayed:

```
(Mock "PayrollItem_1001").update_attributes(any args)
    expected: 1 time
    received: 0 times
./payroll_items_controller_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in '
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually make a request (`get`, `post`, `put` etc.) to the controller in order for the mock to have anything to check.

So for example:

```
it "should find PayrollItem and return object" do
  PayrollItem.should_receive(:find).with("0").and_return(@payroll_item)
  put :update, :id => "0"
end
```

In addition to that, looking at your code, you have some inconsistencies with your return values: in your `before` block you're stubbing `PayrollItem.find` with an id of `1` to return something, and then in your first spec you're mocking it with an id of `0` to return the same thing.

It's fine to both stub and mock the same method because they fulfill different functions: a stub makes sure that the code runs smoothly, while the mock actually checks an expectation. However, you should be stubbing/mocking it for the same argument, so that all the specs using this `before` block are testing the same thing.